# Cannot view tables on AWS RDS SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, sql-server-express, rds

I have an AWS RDS sql-micro instance running SQL Server Express. I have been able to successfully connect to the database using both Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (PC) and RazorSQL (Mac). I would like to view and update records but none of the tables are visible.

Under the 'Tables' folder I can see a 'System Tables' folder and a 'FileTables' folder, both are empty.

I suspect this may be a SQL permissions issue with my user account, but I'm not too familiar with AWS RDS or SQL Server Express.

Comment: How do you know there *are* tables in there? Who created them? If you can't even see the tables, you can't write to them either. Shouldn't you ask the database administrator for permissions?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have inherited the application from a 3rd party development team. The application is working as expected and I haven't made any changes to the database so its likely that the tables and data are still intact. I'm don't know if this definitely is a permissions problem, my knowledge of the tech used in this stack is limited.

Comment: @Richard did you find the solution? I am stuck on same issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with AWS Permissions. Check if the SQL Server user you are using has the correct permissions.